# Windows 10 - Error code 2330 occurs when trying to uninstall or change program

Tags: node.js, windows-10

Every time I try to **uninstall**, **change** or **reinstall** Nodejs application, **the process ends with error 2330**.

The problem started when I was trying to install a new npm package, but this error popped up in bash:

```
npm install Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
```

I tried to reinstall Nodejs, but without success. I am not even able to delete the npm_modules folder inside Nodejs directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem on Windows 10 by downloading this **Microsoft Troubleshooter**. :-)

The inability to **uninstall, change or reinstall** the program was related to the **registry**.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d